# Edit font of single word in sentence in R Shiny Heading

Tags: css, r, shiny

How would I go about editing the font of a single word in an R script? i.e. get just "THIS" to be bold.

```
  fluidPage( h5("Some text change THIS word to bold.")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could try this: `tags$h5("Some text change THIS word to bold.")`.

Answer (score 1):

In shiny you can implement direct HTML tags using `HTML()`

```
 fluidPage(
         HTML("<h5>Some text change <b>THIS</b> word to bold.</h5>")
  )
```